# facebook app action in user timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

i made a facebook app, i googled it many times but not place gave me an answer

all what i want is to post on the facebook app users timeline.

something like socialcam app, when user watch a video you will be able to read on that user timeline that he/she watched that video.

you can access my app from this link and i will appreciate if you can tell me how can i post in user timeline

http://apps.facebook.com/asmgxtestonetwo/?qtnid=20

Comment: Start here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/ - your question is far too broad to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  Open Graph Actions (there's a built-in action "watch") and post onto the timeline using Aggregations:

- [Open Graph Actions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/opengraph/actions/)
- [How-To: Defining an Aggregation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/defining-an-aggregation/)